# Server validation errors in backbone view

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I'm trying to validate my backbone on both sides with backbone.validation, but cant handle server errors properly... looks like I miss triggering right event on the model or my request workflow sucks.

My server response looks like that

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "errors": {
    "oldPin": {
      "param": "oldPin",
      "msg": "Invalid pin"
    },
    "newPinRepeat": {
      "param": "newPinRepeat",
      "msg": "New Pin does not match.",
      "value": "1111"
    }
  }
}
```

When obtating such response, I try to foreach on errors array and pass results to backbone.validation

```
_.each($.parseJSON(res.responseText).errors,function(item){
  console.log(item);
  ????
});
```

I've looked on exposed events in backbone.validation like validated, validated:valid, validated:invalid, but they're not enough to integrate...

Comment: I found the answer on github closed tickets - you should use global method - Backbone.Validation.callbacks.invalid(view, attr, error, selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on github closed tickets - you should use global method - Backbone.Validation.callbacks.invalid(view, attr, error, selector)